# Python unittest - Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-module

So I want to do this code [Kata](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/) for practice.
I want to implement the kata with tdd in separate files:

The algorithm:

```
# stringcalculator.py  
def Add(string):
   return 1
```

and the tests:

```
# stringcalculator.spec.py 
from stringcalculator import Add
import unittest

class TestStringCalculator(unittest.TestCase):
    def add_returns_zero_for_emptyString(self):
        self.assertEqual(Add(' '), 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When running the testfile, I get:

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

It should return one failed test however. What do I miss here?

Comment: Pretty sure you need `test` somewhere in the method name.

Comment: The `TestCase` methods to be run must start with `'test'`!

Comment: Yes! Strange, did not know about this restriction. Thank you kind sirs.

Comment: How are you calling the test file?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

As stated in the python unittest [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html):

> The simplest TestCase subclass will simply implement a test method
>   (i.e. a method whose name starts with test)

So you will need to change your method name to something like this:

```
def test_add_returns_zero_for_emptyString(self):
    self.assertEqual(Add(' '), 0)
```

Comment: I was struggling, without having **test** as the prefix for my method name.

Comment: thanks, never expected this silly mistake i was doing.

Comment: I had the same issue. Changed my function name from `TestMyFunc` to `testMyFunc` and that solved the issue for me

Answer (score 20):

Sidenote: Also, the name of the file in which all the tests are there should start with 'test_'

Comment: You mean for convention?

Comment: For convention purpose yes, and also if you use tools like **nose** to run unit tests. If the file name begins with 'test_' , only then nose can discover the tests inside it and run them.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. My root cause was that I had placed the execution block for unittest.main inside the Test class. This kept messaging RAN 0 tests. Moving it outside of class work.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I added `__init__.py` to the current test directory and the problem goes away.

Comment: this should be the top answer :(

Answer (score 2):

Same symptoms, but different problem. Make sure you're not mixing up tabs and spaces for indentation. The problem may occur when you copy the code from an online resource and update it to your needs. Since tabs and spaces look very much alike in most editors, the test function may simply not be defined correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestStringCalculator(unittest.TestCase):
    def add_returns_zero_for_emptyString(self):
        self.assertEqual(Add(' '), 0)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     unittest.main()
```

After considering above two points in above written code,
I got below error due to prefix space at line ( `if __name__ == '__main__'`)

```
python3 test_flaskr.py 
  File "test_flaskr.py", line 66
    if __name__ == '__main__':
                             ^
```

Ensure that there is no prefix space and you need to write code at 1st column as below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Do not define `__init__`](https://techoverflow.net/2020/04/21/how-to-fix-python-unittest-__init__-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given/); per that link, use `def setUp(self)` instead and unittest will call it.  Also, do not define `run`; I renamed mine to `_run` and the problem finally went away.