# "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s "

Tags: python

I wrote the following code for testing my class but the "Ran 0 tests in 0.000" Error occured:

```
import unittest

from survey import AnonymousSurvey

class TestAnonymousSurvey(unittest.TestCase):

      def test_store_single_response(self):

         question="Which language did you first learn to speak?"

         my_survey=AnonymousSurvey(question)

         my_survey.store_response('English')

         self.assertIn('English',my_survey.responses)

if __name__=='__main__':

  unittest.main()
```

Comment: Show us how you're running the test.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python unittest - Ran 0 tests in 0.000s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43957860/python-unittest-ran-0-tests-in-0-000s)

Comment: @FishingCode The class does contain a method name that begins with "test", so presumably that isn't the cause here.

Comment: @JohnGordon what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I mean, how are you running the tests?  Are you typing a command?  If so, what command?  Or are you running the tests from a GUI?

Comment: @JohnGordon yeah i wrote a method which begins with test

Comment: @JohnGordon i run the programm in Terminal

Comment: What exact command are you typing?

Comment: @JohnGordon i didnt write any command for my programm

Comment: You have to be typing **some** command, that gives the "Ran 0 tests in 0.000" output...

Comment: Oh lord.. @vida he means if you use something like `python -m unittest`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give an input for the `question`, the `AnonymousSurvery(question)` initializes the survey:

```
     getResponse = input("Which language did you first learn to speak?")
     latestResponse = my_survery.store_response(getResponse)  

     self.assertIn("English", latestResponse)
```

Continue on with the main function below...